# Passing value from single C# dropdown selection to a query string

Tags: .net, asp.net, listbox, telerik, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` and a `ListBox` that are functioning fine. I need to be able to insert the selected value from the `DropDownList` into the database when the user moves a selection from the `Products` table to the `ProductsMail` table in the `ListBox`. I have attempted to modify the SQL string multiple times with no success like `"+EmailDDN.SelectedItem+"` and `"+EmailDDN.SelectedValue+"`, etc. I can get the selected value to display in the `EmailLabel1` Label but not in the query. Please provide a solution.
I appreciate your time.
_ JT

Hi suryakiran,

In the "DestinationDataSource":

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE ProductsMail SET Name = @Name, Email = @Email, EmailID = @EmailID WHERE ID = @ID".
```

I have attempted modifications such as:

```
"UPDATE ProductsMail SET Name = @Name, Email = ' + @Email + ', EmailID = @EmailID WHERE ID = @ID" and "UPDATE ProductsMail SET Name = @Name, Email = ' +EmailDDN.SelectedItem+ ', EmailID = @EmailID WHERE ID = @ID"
```

and others with no success.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IPdataConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM [aspnet_Membership]"
    runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  <label for="EmailDDN">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" class="text">Select Email:&nbsp;</asp:Label>
  </label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="EmailDDN" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
    AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="Email" DataValueField="Email" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDN_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>
           Select your email address
    </asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel1" runat="server" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel2" />
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
  <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="RadListBox1" DataSourceID="SourceDataSource"
    AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" DataKeyField="ID" DataTextField="Name" DataSortField="SortOrder"
    Width="230px" Height="200px" AllowTransfer="true" TransferToID="RadListBox2" TransferMode="Copy"
    AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" />
  <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="RadListBox2" DataSourceID="DestinationDataSource"
    AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" DataKeyField="ID" DataTextField="Name" DataSortField="SortOrder"
    Width="230px" Height="200px" AllowReorder="true" AutoPostBackOnReorder="true" AllowDelete="True"
    AutoPostBackOnDelete="true" />
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SourceDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IPdataConnectionString %>"
  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Products WHERE ID = @ID"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Products (Name, ID, Email, EmailID) VALUES (@Name, @ID, @Email, @EmailID)"
  SelectCommand="SELECT Name, ID, Email FROM Products" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Products SET Name = @Name, Email = @Email, EmailID = @EmailID WHERE ID = @ID">
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmailID" Type="Int32" />
  </UpdateParameters>
  <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
  </DeleteParameters>
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmailID" Type="Int32" />
  </InsertParameters>
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EmailDDN" DefaultValue="Select One" Name="Email"
      PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DestinationDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IPdataConnectionString %>"
  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM ProductsMail WHERE ID = @ID"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO ProductsMail (Name, ID, Email, EmailID) VALUES (@Name, @ID, @Email, @EmailID)"
  SelectCommand="SELECT Name, ID, Email FROM ProductsMail" UpdateCommand="UPDATE ProductsMail SET Name = @Name, Email = @Email, EmailID = @EmailID WHERE ID = @ID">
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmailID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
  </UpdateParameters>
  <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
  </DeleteParameters>
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmailID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
  </InsertParameters>
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EmailDDN" DefaultValue="Select One" Name="Email"
      PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
============================================
============================================
protected void DDN_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  EmailLabel1.Text = EmailDDN.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You define the sql data sources there and update the email label on select-change, but where do you actually call the database update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you have used an `<asp:ControlParameter>` in the `<SelectParameters>` section you can pass your email value in by doing this in the `<UpdateParameters>` section.

```
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Email" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ControlID="EmailDDN" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmailID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
  </InsertParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks rtpHarry, that did the trick! One addotional question. My ID column in the Products table is configured as "[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,". When the Insert occurs, the ProductsMail ID column receives NULL instead of the numerical value. How can I get it to insert?

Comment: You should really start a new thread for a new question but I think probably you can just remove the whole <asp:Parameter> and the @ID from the insert. You just ignore it as its an auto incrementing identity column it should fill itself when you add a new record.